# error to connect on remote mysql database

Tags: mysql, vb.net, vb.net-2010

So, I´ve an application that comunicates with a remote mysql db, so its on hostinger and works properly for more de 2 years, and few days ago its just stop working, and the error happens when I try to open connection, the error its about it ↓

**The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format**

but what i dont get is, I´ve tested the same connection on 2 different compannies, and on  hostinger its doesnt work, but on another works fine....Im using vb.net and remote mysql on hostinger...

I´d like to know if someone could help me...

the code just to test open the connection is ↓

```
Dim conn As String = "Server=myserver-here;Port=3306;Database=u8424_test;Uid=u8424_teste;Pwd=Test2021"

        Using cn = New MySqlConnection(conn)

            Try
                cn.Open()
                MsgBox("SUCESS")
                cn.Close()
                MsgBox("CLOSING CONNECTION")
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("SOME ERROR..." & vbNewLine & ex.ToString)
            End Try

        End Using
```

since then, thanks for everyone!

Comment: look in the mysql error log if there is something wrong

Comment: @nbk thanks, I´ll contact the hostinger and talk about this, in fact I´ve alredy chat with them, but they said that with them is everything ok, but I believe that something changed from their side, cause its working fine for more than 2 years, and just stoped :/

Comment: i would check with wireshark the connection and see if there is a hint for a network problem

Comment: @nbk, I think dont, cause I tested in different places, my home and work, and at the work I´ve 2 links of internet and in both of them happens same error....but the most strange is, in another companie of hosting that a have access the same code, with the diffent access data of course, works fine... :/ anyway thanks for any help ;)

Comment: obs* I dont think so

Comment: Little bit of an outside chance, have had something similar in the past.  Turned out my ani malware was doing a redirect on internet traffic

Comment: @Hursey thanks for try to help, but I dont think thats is, cause I´ve tried on 3 different links and at my work I´ve a pc to test somethings and this machine doesnt has any protection, anyway thanks for contribution ;)

Answer (score 0):

so in my case, I got the solution, in fact the problem was on hostinger, that changed their configuration and now we´ve to put the param about ssl in the end of the connection string, something like this already works here for me↓

```
Dim conn As String = "Server=myserver-here;Database=u8424_test;Uid=u8424_teste;Pwd=Test2021;ssl mode=none;"
```

even if you dont use ssl, you must put something, but you have to pass this param or some of these list ↓

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlSslMode.htm